# XElement Sequence contains no elements why?

Tags: c#, google-maps, xelement

Here is the XML I am querying:

```
<GeocodeResponse>
  <status>OK</status>
  <result>
    <type>street_address</type>
    <formatted_address>264 Mugga Ln, Canberra ACT, Australia</formatted_address>
    <address_component>
      <long_name>264</long_name>
      <short_name>264</short_name>
      <type>street_number</type>
    </address_component>
    <address_component>
      <long_name>Mugga Lane</long_name>
      <short_name>Mugga Ln</short_name>
      <type>route</type>
    </address_component>
    <address_component>
      <long_name>Canberra</long_name>
      <short_name>Canberra</short_name>
      <type>colloquial_area</type>
      <type>locality</type>
      <type>political</type>
    </address_component>
    <address_component>
      <long_name>Australian Capital Territory</long_name>
      <short_name>ACT</short_name>
      <type>administrative_area_level_1</type>
      <type>political</type>
    </address_component>
  </result>
</GeocodeResponse>
```

And here is my C# code:

```
XElement localityname = xml.Element("result").Elements("address_component")
                           .Where(a => a.Element("type").Value == "locality")
                           .First().Element("long_name");
```

In most cases, the same/similar XML works fine and I get a value from my query.

What I'm looking for (and works most of the time) is the word "Canberra".

But why does this XML crash with "Sequence contains no elements"???

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple `type` nodes in the xml, so you have to do like this using `XDocument`:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(XML);

    var element = xdoc.Descendants("result").Descendants("address_component")
                      .Where(x=>x.Descendants("type").Any(y=> y.Value == "locality"))
                      .First().Element("long_name");
```

I have made a [working Fiddle example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7QOFWQ)

But if the element may exist or may not in the xml, then consider using `FirstOrDefault()`, as it will not throw exception if no element is found matching the criteria  of predicate:

```
var element = xdoc.Descendants("result").Descendants("address_component")
                          .Where(x=>x.Descendants("type").Any(y=> y.Value == "locality"))
                          .FirstOrDefault();

 if(element !=null)
 {
   var val = element.Element("long_name").Value;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If `xml` is your `XDocument`, then you are ignoring the `GeocodeResponse` element.

This query would probably be more forgiving (returning `null` if the element you're looking for isn't present):

```
var name = (string)doc.Descendants("address_component")
    .Where(e => (string)e.Element("type") == "locality")
    .Select(e => e.Element("long_name"))
    .SingleOrDefault();
```